# I have enough memory but I can't install anything!

Tags: installation, insufficient-memory, lg

When I try to install an app that is 13 mb it is downloaded but when the part of the installation comes it can't be installed it says I don't have enough space. I tried downloading the apk file of that application and still I downloaded it successfuly and I couldn't install it because it said i don't have enough memory even if I have 250mb. I am using Lg L Fino and It is rooted. Please help if you know how. I appreciate all of your answers and I will give you more infromations if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Next to the "marked duplicate", our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) is a good starter to learn about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It has happened on my past phone, (LG L70). 
As my experience, If you want to install new app directly from Play Store, make sure you have at least 400 MB internal storage free space

Comment: I tried with the apk files too